# EF Core 6 HasDefaultValueSql with multiple sequences

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently re-writing an old service, and ran into an issue.

In the SQL Server we have a sequence for each clients product number. The old version used stored procedures for creating products. But I was looking into if it was possible to do something with `HasDefaultValueSql`.

The MS docs said to use `.HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR sequence")`, but is there some way to differentiate which sequence to use based on the client_id column?

My product entity type configuration:

```
builder.ToTable("products");
builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("product_id")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

builder.Property(e => e.ClientId).HasColumnName("client_id");
builder.Property(e => e.Number).HasColumnName("number")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR client_idProductNumberSequence");

builder.Property(e => e.Name).HasColumnName("name");
builder.Property(e => e.Description).HasColumnName("description");
...other props

builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.ClientId, e.Number })
    .IsUnique(true);
```

If thats not possible, what would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: You already specified the sequence you want. Do you want a different sequence for different rows? `HasDefaultValue` specifies the expression used for a `DEFAULT` constraint. It can't use syntax that can't be used in a `DEFAULT` constraint. Have you tried using, eg `CASE` or `IIF`? How do you decide which sequence to use?

Comment: "How do you decide which sequence to use" - thats what im asking, how to get around. Cause I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: *You* have to tell us what the logic is. We can't guess why you can't use a single sequence. How many sequences are there, how do you decide *now* which one to use? If the logic is too complex it's probably better to *not* use a DEFAULT constraint. If that was possible, there would be no need for a stored procedure. The alternative would be to retrieve the sequence values on the client and assign them explicitly

Comment: If you need custom code to generate the new values, you can use a custom value generator and specify it with [HasValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasvaluegenerator?view=efcore-6.0). A custom generator type [inherits from the ValueGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.valuegenerator-1?view=efcore-6.0) class

Comment: There's a sequence for each client, as our clients don't know about each other, they can't have a shared sequence. the sequences are named by client_idProductNumberSequence as stated in the code example above.

Comment: I'll have a look at HasValueGenerator thank you.

Comment: Solved it by making an extension method on the DbContext to get the next value from a named sequence, I can call in a value generator `var nextProductNumberForClient = _productRepository.Context.GetNextSequenceValue($"{client.Namespace}ProductNumber");`

Thank you, for your comments.

Comment: @KasperVerner Could you please share the solution ?